# Refreezing apple pie

Tags: storage-method, freezing, apple-pie

My mom will be traveling via plane this holiday season. She has a frozen apple pie.

By the time she arrives at her destination (my sister's house), the pie will have thawed. Could she then cook it and refreeze it before bringing it to my house?

There are too many days in-between for her to cook it at my sister's house and then leave it in the refrigerator.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @Donna - Would she consider shipping it in dry ice directly to your house?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [New York Department of Agriculture](http://www.agriculture.ny.gov/FS/consumer/thawed.html), fruit pies can be refrozen after thawing, but their quality will degrade. It's only apples and pastry when you think about it, so not much to spoil. It will probably dry out though.